# Ember.js nested routes

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, web-applications, ember.js

Cheers! I've got routes:

```
TravelClient.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tours', function() {
    this.resource('tour', { path: ':tour_id' }, function(){
      this.route('seats');
    });   
  });
});
```

And a template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tour/seats">
    {{...}}
  </script>
```

Seats is an attribute of Tour object:

```
TravelClient.Tour.find(1).get('seats');
12
```

And I extend my TourSeats route like this:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return TravelClient.Tour.find(params.tour_id).get('seats');
  }
});
```

Question: how to render tour's seats in template?

**UPDATE:**

My fixtures looks like that:

```
TravelClient.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

TravelClient.Tour = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  seats: DS.attr('number')
});

TravelClient.Tour.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "Brighton, England",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor ... .",
  seats: 12
},...
```

And I've changed my route extend to this:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return TravelClient.Tour.find(params.tour_id);
  }
});
```

And in template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tour/seats">
    {{tour.seats}}
  </script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tour/seats">
    {{controller.model.seats}}
  </script>
```

and it gives undefind back.
After some debugging I founded out, that there is no any id in params and params is empty, thats why I can't get the right model in TourSeatsRoute function.

Comment: Dont you need params inside the function parameters? Just like you have it in the second one. `model: function(params) {`

Comment: Oh yeah, I did like that, it's obvious, just pasted here the wrong edit. Anyway, the problem is still there.

Comment: check for update in the answer, please.

Comment: To get access to model from parent resource from nested route:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14688346/1662820

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using ember-1.0-pre.4+, the params are only returned for the specific route you're on, not the whole URL. There's some [discussion about this here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1769).

I believe the desired approach at this time is to use `this.modelFor` passing the name of the parent resource you've set up in the parent route. So in your case, it would be:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor("tour");
  }
});
```

Comment: oh thanks, I've already made this workaround `setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('tour.seats').set('model', this.modelFor('tour'));
  }` , but your answer is "ember-way".

Answer (score 2):

You just need to return the model from the `model` method:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return TravelClient.Tour.find(params.tour_id);
  }
});
```

And then in your template you can do the following where `controller` is the context:

```
{{model.seats}}
```

Comment: You have `{{tour.seats}}` whereas in mine its `model`, which is special in EmberJS. When you pass in a model to the controller, it will always be `{{model.property}}`: `{{model.seats}}`

Comment: Which is the same as saying: `{{controller.model.seats}}`

Comment: `{{log controller.model.seats}}` gives undefind! What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to EmberJS but I would've written my router and routes like this.

I'm not sure that you need to wrap the *post* resource inside the *posts* resource. Note the double plurals in ToursSeatsRoute

```
TravelClient.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tours', function() {        
    this.route('/:tour_id/seats');        
  });
});
```

This would give you the following urls:

/tours  - you could map this to an ArrayController

/tours/:tour_id/seats  - you could map this to an ObjectController

```
TravelClient.ToursSeatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(params); 
    return TravelClient.Tour.find(params.tour_id);
  }
});
```

Give it a go? Or maybe put your code a in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I need to wrap this to use it's outlets the way I need. The question is - how to access the parent's resource route's model from nested route?

Comment: I was under the impression that you if you are nesting resources you will need to supply an id for each nested resource... so with the structure you have described you will have a url that looks like: *tours/:tours_id/tour/:tour_id/seats*.   Are the tours and tour resources different entities?

Comment: No, it's the same entities, ArrayController and ObjectController.

Comment: I don't really understand what your're trying to achieve. Why do you want to nest the same resource type?... I have updated my answer to show the example urls that would be generated by my suggested resource mapping

Comment: I need to get access to tour model, which is in parent route TourRoute, from nested route TourSeatsRoute. All simple.
I already have url the same as in your updated answer - just look the question. I already have Tours ArrayController and Tour ObjectController, but seats is an attribute of Tour model, not standalone model itself.

Comment: Well.. My suggestion is to have one resource for posts with nested route for the seats. Sorry I can't help with your nested resource configuration